# How to make Svelte work - right now it only works when triggered by code change

Tags: svelte

I'm having problems with Svelte not working on npm run dev  but any changes to code (HMR) triggers a fix. Here is the code:

```
<script>
  import { onMount, beforeUpdate, afterUpdate } from "svelte";

  let press = 1200,
    temp = 25,
    density;
//prettier-ignore
  onMount(async () => {
    const res = await Module.PropsSI("D","P",+press * 6894.75729,"T",+273.15 + temp,"Xenon");
   density = await res;
  });
</script>

{#await density}
  <h1>Loading...</h1>
{:then value}
  <p>Pressure is {press}, temperature is {temp}, density is {value}</p>
{/await}
```

How do I fix this problem? I'm using webpack template. Would greatly appreciate help!

Gani --

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `density` to something that is not a promise but then, you write `{#await density}`. When you write `{#await density}`, `density` must be a promise.

So you could just remove the whole `onMount` and instead write

```html
<script>
  let press = 1200,
    temp = 25,
    density = Module.PropsSI("D", "P", +press * 6894.75729, "T", +273.15 + temp, "Xenon");
</script>

{#await density}
  <h1>Loading...</h1>
{:then value}
  <p>Pressure is {press}, temperature is {temp}, density is {value}</p>
{/await}
```

Answer (score 0):

@christian, unfortunately your suggestion didn't work. I got this error.

```
  Failed to init component
   <App2>

  instance@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:9265:20
  init@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:11065:11
  App2@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:9291:56
  createProxiedComponent@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:9075:9
  ProxyComponent@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:8648:92
  Proxy<App2>@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:8740:11
  ./src/main.js@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:13655:13
  __webpack_require__@http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:13692:33
  @http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:14848:30
  @http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js:14852:12
```

But when I treat it as promise (and making small fix and saving - notice the comment //resolve(dens) and then removing, the problem goes away and I get the right answer.
Here is a Promise version

```
    <script>
    let press=1200,temp=25, rho=[];
  
    function density() {
        dens = Module.PropsSI("D", "P",+press * 6894.75729,"T", +273.15 + temp, "Xenon");
        rho = dens;
   }

    // works
     let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      const dens =  Module.PropsSI("D", "P",+press * 6894.75729,"T", +273.15 + temp, "Xenon");
     rho = dens;
     //resolve(dens); // immediately 
    });
```

This gives the right answer:

Density is 1622.199574557037

Comment: PropsSI is from a wasm+js wrapper. It's called in index.html as <script src='coolprop.js'></script>. I think the problem is with svelte loader which doesn't load the coolprop before first HMR.